# Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform Version 6.1.2 gives upload error

Tags: uwp

A simple test app could be uploaded to the store without error.

Changing `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` Version 6.0.8 to 6.1.2 gives the upload error:

> The declared package dependency does not exist. Dependency: `Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.2.1`. Minimum version: 2.1.26417.0.

I use VS 15.7.0 Preview 5.0 with .NET Framework Version 4.7.02556 and build 16299.
What should I check to find out the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This problem has happened before, there are multiple reasons why this might be happening. See [this thread on forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d854ce93-ef54-4832-8d3a-e6f81ac0f1fa/uwp-error-your-package-microsoftnetnativeframework16-specifies-version-16254050-but?forum=windowsstore).

The key takeaways are:

- Try to clear NuGet cache and resubmit
- It is possible that Store is not yet ready to accept a package with this version of `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform`. Try contacting Microsoft Dev Center support to verify this.
- File a bug [here on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/tree/master/releases/UWP). It might be the fastest way to reach an answer.

Even from the GitHub page it seems the .NET Native 2.1 is not yet ready (the README says it is coming early May).